# Python MySQLdb execute return int

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.5.2 for my project. I installed `MySQLdb` via *pip* for Mysql connection.

Code:

```
import MySQLdb

class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="*", passwd="*", db="*")
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def query(self, q):
        r = self.cur.execute(q)
        return r

def test():
    db = DB()
    result = db.query('SELECT id, name FROM test')
    return print(result)

def test1():
    db = DB()
    result = db.query('SELECT id, name FROM test').fetchall()
    for res in result:
        id, name = res
        print(id, name)

test()
test1()
#test output >>> '3'
#test1 output >>> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

Test table:

```
id     |     name
1      |    'test'
2      |    'test2'
3      |    'test3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this link：http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

> > At this point your query has been executed and you need to get the
> >     results. You have two options:
> >
> > r=db.store_result()
> >
> > ## ...or...  r=db.use_result() Both methods return a result object. What's the difference? store_result() returns the entire result set to
> >
> > the client immediately. If your result set is really large, this could
> >     be a problem. One way around this is to add a LIMIT clause to your
> >     query, to limit the number of rows returned. The other is to use
> >     use_result(), which keeps the result set in the server and sends it
> >     row-by-row when you fetch. This does, however, tie up server
> >     resources, and it ties up the connection: You cannot do any more
> >     queries until you have fetched all the rows. Generally I recommend
> >     using store_result() unless your result set is really huge and you
> >     can't use LIMIT for some reason.

```
def test1():
    db = DB()
    db.query('SELECT id, name FROM test')
    result = db.cur.fetchall()
    for res in result:
        id, name = res
        print(id, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

cursor.execute() will return the number of rows modified or retrieved, just like in PHP. Have you tried to return the fetchall() like so?

```
 def query(self, q):
   r = self.cur.execute(q).fetchall()
   return r
```

See here for more documentation: https://ianhowson.com/blog/a-quick-guide-to-using-mysql-in-python/

Comment: this is wrong, it will return error like '' int can't be iterated'